# Why does closing tutum/wordpress automatically delete all the app and data?

Tags: wordpress, docker

I am new to docker, and trying to run a Wordpress application using this tutum/wordpress image: https://hub.docker.com/r/tutum/wordpress/

I simply follow this step: docker run -d -p 80:80 tutum/wordpress

But when I turn off the computer, and run it again, all the database + application gone. And I need to restart from scratch.

How do I persist the database and application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That image is deprecated. So you should be using the official wordpress image

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

Then use `docker-compose up` to get the wordpress up. The wordpress image has code located at `/usr/src/wordpress`. So if you need to persist the plugins directory then you need to use volumes to map it like I did for mysql

Comment: Man, only if I stumble upon this earlier. Yes, I am now using that config, but not yet for the volume of wordpress. So, if previously my data for wordpress is not persisted in volumes, how do I move it to new volume? Shall I do backup manually and move it to host and later restore it to volume? And how do I save that volume to another backup file? Sorry for noob question here

Comment: Load the image once. The folder will be on host. On the host you can just copy the existing folders and copy them to the host path you specified for the volume